# Splitting a big Power Trace to several smaller

Tags: pcb, design, trace

I would ask if i can layout a big trace and split it into many smaller ones (see attachement)
[image]

I need to run a trace capable of handling ~5A. But the trace would be too thick to fit between the pins (screw terminals). My idea was to run a big trace and then use smaller traces (2mm)from the screw terminal to the big rail.
Is that OK or wold it burn the board?
Its homemade btw.

~Straw

Comment: if small traces' total width is greater than the big trace's width.. i will wait for other answers

Comment: there are actually 7 more "mini" traces with 2mm, so this fits.

Comment: There is a tool for for calculating trace widths [here](http://www.desmith.net/NMdS/Electronics/TraceWidth.html) but in principle multiple parallel paths instead of one big one is fine provided they are all routed similarly and share the current (nearly) equally

Answer (score 4, accepted):

2mm trace is about 78mil.

For an external trace carrying 5A that heats up by 20.2 K.

Assuming you mis-etch by 10%, leaves >= 70mil.

With 6A gives a rise of 31.8 K.

So at ambient of 30degrees C a single 2mm trace on top or bottom carrying 6A with good enough manual etching will become about 62 degrees Celcius.

That may not be very good for a precision board, but it's not dangerous. So it'd be good to split it over 3 traces that are within 25% of the same length, but especially if they are short and connected to fatter traces, their heat will also be wicked away. If you make it 1cm between large traces that are 0.75mm or more wide, you will not see much extra heating at all from a single 2mm trace. But it is better to have a main trace >4mm wide and two or more 2mm traces, to reduce the voltage drop.

For reference, the estimated voltage drops for 10cm of trace at several widths with 6A (I use 6A because you say ~5A and it's better to use too much than too little):

- 2mm: 0.111V (heating =~ 26K)
- 3mm: 0.072V (heating =~ 20K)
- 4mm: 0.052V (heating =~ 14.5K)
- 5mm: 0.041V (heating =~ 12 K)

So, depending on the length you may already be overestimating the need for a certain size of traces.

This does assume the final trace is the size stated with slightly under etched sides, so if you manually etch take a decent margin. I.e. if 3mm would be acceptable it's good to use 4mm, etc.

### EDIT, by request:

If you have no engineering handbook for electronics design with all the normal, integral and differential maths to do with anything ever, you can also use the Saturn PCB tool to calculate numbers like the above ones, which I used in this case, because I didn't want to spend too much time on it:

[The Saturn PCB tool](http://www.saturnpcb.com/pcb_toolkit.htm), free download from http://saturnpcb.com

Comment: How did you calculate the temperature rise of the trace?

Comment: @Golaž the formulas are undoubtedly on Google, but I often use the Saturn PCB Tool from saturnpcb.com which is free. If I need to really know it for 100% sure I sometimes recalculate with my design handbook, which has all the maths for just about everything, but I can't be arsed to scan it. :-)

Comment: Just a small question about calculating the width: a external trace is usually in contact with air, but is it still a  external trace when i put solder mask on it, or do i need to use the calculation for a internal layer?

Comment: @MatzeStrawberrymaker  Solder mask is not considered to make it an internal layer. Solder mask is microscopic in thickness and the implications of colour differences are negligible at the scale of temperatures you should want to stick to.